# Wput error size fail

Tags: file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload the files to my shared linux hosting domain since i am new to this utility please help me whats going wrong. Details are as follows

```
domain : mydomain.in
user : ftp_user
pwd : pwd
destination folder : /upload (Permission 777)
host os: windows 7 32 Bit
server : Linux shared hosting
Terminal : cmd with Admistrative Rights

wput bpp_config.ini --verbose -o log.txt ftp://ftp_user:pwd@mydomain.in/upload
```

output of log.txt

```
--10:04:02-- `bpp_config.ini'
    => ftp://ftp_user:xxxxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:21/upload
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xx:21... connected# --------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep]     [TLS] ----------
# You are user number 4 of 50 allowed.
# Local time is now 10:04. Server port: 21.
# IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
!
==> AUTH TLS ... done (communication is now encrypted!)
Logging in as xxx ... Logged in!
==> SIZE upload ... failed.
==> TYPE I ... done.
Setting data protection level to private ... done.
==> PASV ... done.
connection failed.
==> PORT ... failed.
Send Failed. Waiting 10 seconds... ==> SIZE upload ... failed.
Setting data protection level to private ... done.
==> PASV ... done.
connection failed.
==> PORT ... failed.
Send Failed. Waiting 10 seconds...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your case is not that the SIZE command failed (that's ok if the file doesn't exist yet remotely). However, wput cannot establish a separate data connection to the target server, as you can see through

```
==> PASV ... done.
connection failed.
==> PORT ... failed.
```

When running more verbosely (`-d`) you’ll see to which IP wput is trying to connect. Most likely a firewall is blocking the connection. Try disabling it and it should work.